# React Router v4 <NavLink> vs <Link> benefits

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Besides the ability to set an "activeClassName" and "activeStyle" on NavLink, is there any reason to use **NavLink** over **Link** when creating links to other routes on non-navigational elements (ie. not main nav in header or footer) on your site that don't need an active state/class?

Comment: I can't comment directly to TOUMI (because I don't have 50rep), so I'll add it here. `NavLink` keeps the proper focus on the page for accessibility. When using link, initial focus is lost on page load and you will also notice that tabbing through dropdowns also breaks when using `Link`. NavLink fixes this.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/components/nav-link.md) is clear:

> `<NavLink>`
>
> A special version of the `<Link>` that will add styling attributes to the  rendered element when it matches the current URL.

Thus, the answer is **NO**. There are no other reasons except the mentioned one.

Answer (score 58):

When you need to use style or class attributes on active `<Link>`, then you can use `<NavLink>`

Let see the example:

**Link**

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
```

**NavLink**

```
<NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 15):

**Link Component**

> It is used to create links which allow to navigate on different URLs
>   and When we click on any of that particular **Link**, it should load that page which is associated with that path without reloading the page. 
>   *Example:*

[image]

**NavLink Component:**

> If, we want to add some **styles** to the Link. So that when we click
>   on any particular link, it can be easily identified which Link is
>   active. For this react router provides **NavLink** instead of
>   **Link**. Now replace Link from **Navlink** and add properties **activeStyle**. The **activeStyle** properties mean when we click on the Link, it should be highlighted with different style so that we can
>   differentiate which link is currently active.
>   *Example:*

[image]

Ref: https://www.javatpoint.com/react-router

Answer (score 6):

Simply, 
When you use `<Link>` there isn't any **active** class on selected element.

In contrast, with `<NavLink>` the selected element is highlighted because this element is added an active class.

Hope useful for you.

Comment: Some code sample will help the users. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23612520)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add in v6, `NavLink` adds `.active` class to the `a` tag without any extra piece of code, e.g.

```
<NavLink to="/">Link 1</Link>
<NavLink to="/link2">Link 2</Link>
```

will render as:

```
<a href="/" class='active'>Link 1</Link>
<a href="/link2">Link 2</Link>
```

if the user is on the home URL (https://localhost:3000)

Comment: you are pretty much correct except that <NavLink to="/">Link 1</Link> will render as <a href="/" class='active'>Link 1</Link> because your basic CSS doesn't understands className

Comment: Thanks @HassanArafat, I have updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One difference as of v6.0.0-beta.3 is that activeClassName and activeStyle have been removed from NavLinkProps. Instead, you can pass a function to either style or className that will allow you to customize the inline styling or the class string based on the component's active state. you can also pass a function as children to customize the content of the  component based on their active state, specially useful to change styles on internal elements.

Answer (score 0):

The NavLink is used when you want to highlight a link as active. So, on every routing to a page, the link is highlighted according to the activeClassName . Link is for links that need no highlighting.